# VS Code stuck with "Starting OmniSharp at '/home/...' " message

Tags: c#, ubuntu, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I was trying to use VS-Code with Unity. I installed the C# extension for VS-Code and the required plugins for Unity. But whenever I open the C# project the console shows the following message:

```
 "Starting OmniSharp at '/home/...' "
```

And it just stays there. It doesn't even report failure. Intellisense isn't working either. Which I guess is due to omnisharp not starting.

[Edit] I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS